# Map tiles for Openstreetmaps (OSM) and Google Maps (satellite view) 

Tags: google-maps, tiles, openstreetmap

Are tiles from Openstreetmap (OSM) *compatible* with tiles of Google Maps (satellite view)? 
By compatible I mean - is it possible to use the code/logic that is written to read OSM tiles to load tiles from Google maps?

Can someone point to good resources that can explain more on this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by compatible, you mean "is there an equivelent tile covering the exact same area, for a specific zoom level", then yes, the OpenStreetMap tiles are compatible with Google Maps, and even Bing Maps.

If you want to add OSM map tiles as a layer using the Google Maps API, then you can use code like:

```
var copyOSM = new GCopyrightCollection("<a href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/\">OpenStreetMap</a>");
copyOSM.addCopyright(new GCopyright(1, new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(-90,-180), new GLatLng(90,180)), 0, " "));

var tilesMapnik     = new GTileLayer(copyOSM, 1, 17, {tileUrlTemplate: 'http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png'});
var mapMapnik     = new GMapType([tilesMapnik],     G_NORMAL_MAP.getProjection(), "Mapnik");

map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), { mapTypes: [mapMapnik, G_SATELLITE_MAP] });
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(32.08, 34.82), 12);

map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Currently, I've some code (Java) that uses OSM APIs to download map tiles of a certain area to disk. It is possible to use the same code to get tiles from Google maps ?

Comment: Not legally, but several people in the past have used Fiddler/Firebug and spotted that the X, Y & Z parameters are identical, just with a slightly different URL format.

Comment: can a similar process be used to load the tiles on the iPhone?

Comment: @Aaron To do something like that, you'd need to intercept the cache for the browser, which would be the more challenging step. Alternately, I'd suggest using a native tile renderer, for which there are a few around, rather than a web app.

Comment: thats is what I am asking about... I do not want to use the web browser